# How to draw a matplot lib (python) polar scatter chart in django?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, mpld3

I am writing a web application where I have to draw a polar scatter chart(https://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter_demo.html) in the webpage. The polar scatter chart is generated using python matplotlib and then is converted into JSON format and displayed on the webpage using mpld3 library(https://mpld3.github.io/install.html).

Here is my code to show an empty polar scatter chart:

```
<script src=".../mpld3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src=".../mpld3/mpld3.v0.3.1.dev1.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-7">
<div id="fig01"></div>
<script>
   mpld3.draw_figure("fig01",{"id": "el44281963893827960", "plugins": [{"type": "reset"}, {"type": "zoom", "button": true, "enabled": false}, {"type": "boxzoom", "button": true, "enabled": false}], "height": 480.0, "data": {}, "width": 640.0, "axes": [{"yscale": "linear", "id": "el44281963940408456", "axesbg": "#FFFFFF", "xdomain": [0.0, 6.283185307179586], "images": [], "xlim": [0.0, 6.283185307179586], "axesbgalpha": null, "collections": [], "ydomain": [0.0, 4.0], "markers": [], "texts": [], "xscale": "linear", "lines": [], "sharey": [], "paths": [], "axes": [{"grid": {"color": "#B0B0B0", "alpha": 1.0, "dasharray": "none", "gridOn": true}, "fontsize": 10.0, "scale": "linear", "visible": true, "nticks": 8, "position": "bottom", "tickformat": ["3", "2", "1", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4"], "tickvalues": [0.0, 0.7853981633974483, 1.5707963267948966, 2.356194490192345, 3.141592653589793, 3.9269908169872414, 4.71238898038469, 5.497787143782138]}, {"grid": {"color": "#B0B0B0", "alpha": 1.0, "dasharray": "none", "gridOn": true}, "fontsize": 10.0, "scale": "linear", "visible": true, "nticks": 4, "position": "left", "tickformat": ["Gen 1", "Gen 2", "Gen 3", ""], "tickvalues": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]}], "zoomable": true, "bbox": [0.22375000000000006, 0.10999999999999999, 0.5774999999999999, 0.77], "sharex": [], "ylim": [0.0, 4.0]}]} );
</script>
```

The problem here is that the graph is generated as a normal chart and not as a polar scatter chart which is circular shaped.

Here is that I get after rendering my webpage:

[image]

Where is this is what I am expecting(generated from matplotlib):

[image]

Any idea on how to get this round chart in my webpage? All suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [issue raised in 2015](https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/issues/285) for `mpld3`. Since it's still an open issue, I don't think you will be able to do polar plot with `mpld3` as for now. You might have to turn to alternatives like [this example](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Django.html), using [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to embed Base64 image.